# Как сделать интеграционные тесты при прямой зависимости компонентов?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testng

Нужно сделать интеграционные тесты для приложения с такими условными этапами:

- Stage 1
- Stage 2 (Создается на основе Stage 1).
- Stage 3 (Создается на основе Stage 2).
- Stage 4 (Создается на основе Stage 3).

Каждый stage содержит свой [CRUD](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRUD).

Как на это сделать интеграционные тесты с такой файловой структурой:

- Stage1.test.js
- Stage2.test.js
- Stage3.test.js
- Stage4.test.js

**Что придумал сам:**

1. Сделать pipeline - в одном файле, условно `pipeline.test.js`, описать рабочий сценарий. Но тут есть существенный недостаток, - часть функционала, например, удаление останется нетронутым.
2. Делать по каждому файлу, по всем функциям (эндпоинтам). Тут пожалуй одна проблема - огромная нагрузка на написание самих тестов, а также на их поддержку. Обусловлено тем, что использование того же наследования в тестах не желательно.

**Как быть?**

Comment: Не совсем понятно в чем проблематика, опиши ее. Что мешает написать тесты? Пишешь stage-1 покрываешь тестами, пишешь stage-2 полностью включаешь в его stage-1. Только в stage-2 уже пишешь тесты, которые тестируют именно эту стадию, а первую - нет. Так как она уже покрыта.

Comment: Если же хочешь отвязатся от прямой зависимости, то используй моки, и Dependency Inversion Principle из SOLID. Но я так понимаю тут нужно в следущем стейдже сохранять функционал предыдущего, поэтому просто включаешь одно в другое и всё.